# Как сделать так, чтобы питон не выводил значение из input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть скрипт, который спрашивает у пользователя его имя, вроде:

```
print(input('What\'s your name? '))
```

И в ответ я получаю:

```
What's your name? Boris
Boris
```

Есть ли какой-то способ сделать так, чтобы вывод выглядел так же, но без первой строки? (What's your name? Boris). Или другими словами - как сделать так, чтобы метод input() после ввода - ничего не выводил?

Нашёл способ решения в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087290/prevent-python-from-showing-entered-input) вопросе, но как сказано в комментариях - при использовании того метода - пользователь не видит собственный ввод в терминале. А потому это решение не валидно, так как в моём случае пользователь должен видеть собственный ввод, но как только он нажал клавишу Enter - этот ввод не должен выводиться в окно терминала, пока переменная, использующая этот ввод не будет выведена через print().

Пример желаемого вывода в терминале:

```
Boris
```

Без строки `What's your name? Boris`

Comment: input после ввода ничего не выводит. Обратите внимание на print.

Comment: `name = input('What\'s your name? ')`

Comment: @КириллМалышев так или иначе - когда скрипт подходит к чему-либо, что использует метод input(), будь то аргумент другого метода или переменная - питон выводит строку, которую ввёл пользователь. Если убрать input() из print() и использовать как значение переменной - то пользовательский ввод всё равно останется в терминале. В данном случае мне нужно, чтобы этого вывода в терминале не оставалось

Comment: Проверил - создал скрипт: `input('What\'s your name? ')`, запустил, получил `What's your name?`, напечатал `Boris`. Результат: одна строка в терминале - `What's your name? Boris`. Так и должно быть.

Comment: @MiniMax всё верно, но мне нужно, чтобы в терминале этой строки не было.

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы предложения `What's your name? ` вообще не было (пользователь его не видел), то просто замените его на обычный `input()` без аргумента. Но как тогда пользователь узнает, что ему вводить? Или вы хотите, чтобы вопрос удалился из терминала, после того, как пользователь ввёл ответ?

Comment: @MiniMax Даже если пользователь введёт что-либо в input() (метод без аргумента) - то его ввод всё равно останется в терминале. И в этом вся проблема - мне нужно, чтобы ничего не выводилось после того, как пользователь введёт строку в input(). Грубо говоря - если в input() ввести Boris, то в терминал выведется Boris - строка, которую я не хочу выводить.

Comment: Конечно останется, ведь пользователь ввёл слово `Boris` в терминал, Python здесь не при чём, он не может удалить написанное из терминала. Думаю, можно с помощью Python дать команды терминалу, чтобы он: либо отключил `echo` и не отображал введённые символы (как при вводе пароля), либо затёр введённое слово, после обработки Питоном.

Comment: @MiniMax _"затёр введённое слово, после обработки Питоном"_ Об этом и речь, как я понял. Вы знаете, как можно это сделать? Я пробовал `CSI`, но они не работают из коробки на `Windows 10`.

Comment: @MiniMax ваш последний комментарий звучит как то, что мне нужно. Можете поделиться этими командами, чтобы питон отключил echo и не отображал введённые символы после нажатия Enter?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Написал ответ для Linux. Насчёт Windows не знаю.

Comment: @Gargoyle Наврядли отключение `echo` вам подойдёт, ведь тогда пользователь не будет видеть, что набирает. Это применяется для паролей.

Answer (score 2):

Можно стереть введённое пользователем слово с помощью Escape последовательностей для управления терминалом, в частности положением курсора. Лучше использовать библиотеки, чем непосредственно коды - для независимости от конкретного терминала, но я библиотеками не пользовался, поэтому сказать ничего не могу. В Linux для этих целей есть `tput` утилита.

На Ubuntu я сделал так:

```
print('What\'s your name? ', end='')
print("\033[s", end='')     # Сохраняем положение курсора

name = input()

print("\033[u", end='')     # Восстанавливаем положение курсора
print("\033[K")             # Очищаем строку начиная с текущего
                            # положения курсора до конца
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваше решение выглядит наиболее близким к тому, что мне нужно. Но к сожалению - в моём терминале на Mint поведение скрипта немного иное. В первый раз введённая строка успешно скрылась, как я и хотел, но после повторного запуска скрипта - этот эффект пропал и я снова мог видеть свой ввод

Comment: @Gargoyle Странно, так вести себя не должно. Мой скрипт без всяких добавлений используете? Как запускаете?

Comment: использую без добавлений. и переписывал вручную, и копировал, и пробовал встроить в функцию - ничего не помогло. запускать пробовал через файл и через шелл

Comment: @Gargoyle А терминал какой? У меня `gnome terminal`. Попробуйте для интереса запустить из виртуального терминала: `tty[1-6]` (которые без GUI).

Comment: немного не понимаю как использовать команду. у  меня при tty -1 выводится ошибка. не могли бы вы пояснить, как её использовать?

Comment: @Gargoyle Вот здесь объяснено [Как переключаться между TTY](http://itisgood.ru/2018/08/22/kak-perekljuchatsja-mezhdu-tty-bez-ispolzovanija-funkcionalnyh-klavish-v-linux/). Вам нужна только первая часть, где про `Ctrl` + `Alt` + любая из клавиш с `F1` по `F6`. Чтобы вернуться обратно на рабочий стол нужно сделать тоже самое: с помощью `Ctrl` + `Alt` + любая из клавиш с `F1` по `F6` найти **tty** в котором запущена графическая оболочка (GUI).

Comment: @Gargoyle Как перейдёте в текстовый `tty`, попробуйте запустить вышеупомянутый скрипт - всё также как в терминал эмуляторе (`gnome terminal`, `xterm` и т. д.).

Comment: я запустил ваш скрипт в tty1 и результат был как при использовании обычного input('What\'s your name? '), только после ввода - под введённой строкой появляется пустая строка

Comment: @Gargoyle Что-то здесь не так. В `tty` у нас должно работать одинаково, так как это часть ядра, от дистрибутива не зависит. Предпоследняя строка точно `print("\033[u", end='')`? По описанию выглядит так, будто вы удалили `end=''` и у вас `print("\033[u")`. Я это сделал и получил то, о чём вы говорите: `Boris` не удаляется, пустая строка снизу добавляется.

Comment: код я не изменял, скопировал всё с вашего примера и вставил в свой файлик. Ваш пример сработал у меня лишь один раз, а далее результат, о котором писал выше, с пустой строкой.

Answer (score 2):

```
import getpass
name = getpass.getpass(prompt="What's your name?")
```

Comment: Зачем вы вызываете в функции print функцию input?

Comment: этот ответ не верен, так как в данном случае пользователь не видит собственный ввод во время набора текста

Comment: Вы толком объясните что вам надо а то хочу что бы видел хочу что бы не видел

Comment: name = input('What\'s your name? ') Тогда так

Comment: результат должен быть как при getpass, но только чтобы пользователь мог видеть, что вводит

Comment: name = input('What\'s your name? ')

Comment: Если вы не напечатаете name пользователь ни когда его не увидит

Comment: кажется вы не поняли сути вопроса. прошу, перечитайте обсуждения выше.

Comment: name = input() а так?

Answer (score 1):

У тебя input задает вопрос, а ты выводишь его с print.
Otvet:
name = input("Whats ur name ?\n")

По факту ты только вводишь значение.